# keycloak - how to update user account email through keycloak endpoint?

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to update user email on keycloak and it throw this exception

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError:
> 500 Internal Server Error: [no body]  at
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:188)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:818)

```
public String UpdateUserData(String email, String userId) {
        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("Authorization", "bearer " + getToken(externalClientId));
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
            map.add("email", email);

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);
            this.client.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            this.client.exchange(clientToConnectionProperties.get(externalClientId).URI +"/users/"+userId, HttpMethod.PUT, request, Void.class);
            return HttpStatus.OK.name();
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.name();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put all already known user fields first

1. GET `/auth/admin/realms/<your realm>/users/<user id>`
2. PUT `/auth/admin/realms/<your realm>/users/<user id>`.
   Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Body (get values from response to the request on step 1):

```json
{
    "id": "<user id>",
    "username": "<username>",
    "enabled": true,
    "emailVerified": true,
    "access": {
        "manageGroupMembership": true,
        "view": true,
        "mapRoles": true,
        "impersonate": true,
        "manage": true
    },
    "email": "<email>
}
```

Comment: thanks xardbaiz
i solved it . the keycloak throw null exception when i call the api like the approve code . maybe because i used an old version . however i change the call to be like this 


restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});



and it works fine.

Comment: my keycloak version is 4.8